# how can I modify my function via ajax?

Tags: php, highcharts

well, to start I used to make my JSON function, but when I wanted add data I couldn't. So  How can I my json function ? i'm using getJSON but I can't add data like ajax  then how could I change it to ajax style. it's for hightchart

```
$(function() {
    var processed_json = new Array();
    $.getJSON('../controllers/chart_controller.php', function(data){
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            processed_json.push([data[i].key,data[i].value]);
        }

        //draw chart
        $('#salesChart').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: "column"
            },
            title: {
                text: "Best selling product"
            },
            xAxis: {
                type: 'category',
                allowDecimals: false,
                title: {
                    text: ""
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: "Scores"
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'Sales',
                data: processed_json
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: doesn't this work? also, can you post what is returned from the getJSON call?

Comment: ?? what is a json function? why a php-tag? to add a property to a json: `myjson.myNewProperty=1;`

Comment: I need to add a data field because im using a switch-case to control every chart that I have, like this  
    url: '../controllers/sales_controller.php',
    type: 'POST',
  data:'select_product='+id+'&txt_amount='+amount+'&boton=add_sale',

Comment: or does anyone has an example with ajax?

Comment: ah, now I get what you want. why don't you make a real (jQuery) ajax call out of getJson? here's the manual: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ There you can easily add a set of data.

Comment: then do I have to remove getJSON?

Comment: well, replace it. keep the draw-chart part of course. that will live in `succes` later! ajax will point to the same php-script, will also return a json. It just offers more possibilities. getJson is kind of a shorthand of ajax.

Comment: i fix it, but when I want to display my chart dont it because my object notation is like this [{"product":"TEST_1","best_selling_product":"305"},{"product":"IPHONE 4S","best_selling_product":"108"}] . how can I change best_selling_product for this "best_selling_product":90. ha im using MYSQLI_ASSOC

Comment: The Highcharts requires to use the y param and value as number not string. So replace custom name "best_selling_product" with "y" and use number (json_encode() with number flag). or in the preprocessing use:  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            processed_json.push([data[i].key, parseFloat(data[i].best_selling_product)]);
        }